# Sinusoidal curve fitting in R

Tags: r, curve

I am trying to fit a sinusoidal curve to data using the following code. I'm not sure why its turning out funky where the lines seemingly go from the observation at 17 to 9 then 9 to 20 and back to 12. I'd also like the sinusoidal curve to extend across the full 24 hours. If you can do this in ggplot2 that would be fantastic. Thanks!

```
Test_case <- structure(list(TEST_RESULT = c(1.31, 65.44, 8.59, 9.91), Time = c(17, 
9, 20, 12)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Time <- test_case$Time
test_result <- test_case$TEST_RESULT
  
xc<-cos(2*pi*Time/24)
xs<-sin(2*pi*Time/24)
fit.lm <- lm(test_result ~ xc+xs)

fit <- fitted(fit.lm)  

# find predictions for original time series
pred <- predict(fit.lm, newdata=data.frame(Time=Time))    

plot(test_result ~ Time, data= test_case, xlim=c(1, 24), ylim=c(0,500))
lines(Time, pred, col="blue")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Time variable appears in the formula and is not hidden by the xc and xs variables.  Also be sure that the times used in the prediction are in order, i.e. 0:23 is in ascending order.  On the other hand, the input data need not be in order since we are only plotting it as points so the order the input data is plotted does not matter.

Thus using `test_case` from the question we have:

```
fit.lm <- lm(test_result ~ cos(2*pi*Time/24) + sin(2*pi*Time/24), test_case)
 
Time2 <- 0:23
pred2 <- predict(fit.lm, newdata = list(Time = Time2))    
 
plot(test_result ~ Time, data = test_case, xlim = c(1, 24), ylim = c(0, 500))
lines(pred2 ~ Time2, col = "blue")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This looks good, can you also extend the sinusoidal curve across the full 24 hours?

Comment: I am not getting the same result as your image. The curve inverted it looks like.

Comment: I did change the answer several times.  Could you try it again  on a fresh instance of R please.  First copy and paste Test_case from the question and then copy and paste the code in the answer.

Comment: One question I have, when I run summary(fit.lm) the intercept is 43.2 but it is clearly above 50 in the plot. Any idea why there is a difference?

Comment: There are only 4 points and 3 parameters so I don't think you can expect much. Suggest you simulate some data with a much larger number of points and compare the result to the model used to generate the data.

Comment: Ah gotcha, yeah I have about 3k cases with only measurements at 4 time points. My idea for getting a range of possible values for the "true" curve is to iteratively run models for all individuals and then find the range of parameter values that 95% of the sample fall within.